# Storing weather forecast data in Swift

Tags: swift, core-data, struct, realm, weather-api

I want to make an application which requires a lot of weather forecast data, three cities, seven days, 24 hours and six values in every hour of forecast.

I'm using the Dark Sky API and pod called ForecastIO.

What should I use for storage? CoreData or Realm? I was told that Realm is a lot of easier to work with and it's also more efficient. I looked into code and for a beginner it is much easier and not dealing with any graphs is also plus, but if it needs to be done, I'll study it. And how should I structure it?

I tried this but Realm accepts only basic data types, so it won't work.

HourlyWeather.swift

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class HourlyWeather: Object {
    @objc dynamic var temperature: Double = 0
    @objc dynamic var wind: Double = 0
    @objc dynamic var precip: Double = 0
    @objc dynamic var humidity: Double = 0
    @objc dynamic var uvIndex: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var icon: String = ""
}
```

DailyWeather.swift

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class DailyWeather: Object {
    @objc dynamic var day = [HourlyWeather()] // I understand that this is a no-no for Realm
}
```

CityWeather.swift

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class CityWeather: Object {
    @objc dynamic var city = [DailyWeather()] // The same
}
```

I wanted this code to be accessible as

```
City.day[index].hour[index].temperature
```

for example

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's not necessary to tell us you're new or inexperienced because we don't care. What we care about is whether you've done your research, tried multiple ways to solve the problem, then written a good question that follows the guidelines. Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" as they will help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `List` instead of `Array` when you want to store a collection of Realm objects as a property of another object. For more information, read the [Many-to-many relationships](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest#many-to-many) part of the official docs (but I'd suggest going through the whole documentation, since it gives a really good starting point for using Realm).

```
class DailyWeather: Object {
    let day = List<HourlyWeather>()
}

class CityWeather: Object {
    let city = List<DailyWeather>()
}
```

Comment: A minor addition is that you are welcome to use Arrays in your Realm objects however they will not be managed by Realm - they are just regular Arrays. e.g. if you load in a DailyWeather object as in your question, the day Array will be an empty array (which could be manually populated). As David said, if you want the object and relationship managed, use a List. If you want an array, you can loose the `@objc dynamic` and just make it a regular var.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a property of type `List`. See the [Many to Many docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest#many-to-many)

```
class DailyWeather: Object {
   let city = List<DailyWeather>()
}
```